# i want to remove the ram cache but getting permission denied error on ubuntu 18.04.3 Lts 64-bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

```
waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.8G        609M        478M        1.3G        1.2G
Swap:          975M        280M        695M
waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ sudo sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `sync` runs with sudo privileges, but not `echo`. Yo can instead do:

```
sudo sync; echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
```